# Why is a friend asking me to make multiple Money Gram transfers in my name using his money?

Tags: united-states, money-transfer, international-transfer, scams, philippines

For the past few months, someone that I know casually is sending money to the Philippines every 2 to 3 days.  He mentioned that the money is going to his family so that they can  use it to travel to United States.  So far, no one has come to United States. He mentioned that he couldn’t send the money because he had met the maximum  amount of money that can be sent.

He puts the MoneyGram form in my name, hands me the money and I go to the counter. I have noticed that he uses  two or three names on the form to collect it. For the first few times that I did this,  I thought that this was OK.  By now, I have probably done this  30 to 40 times.   My issue is that  it's my name on the MoneyGram form as the sender.

Does anyone have an idea of what he is doing and why he can’t fulfill this obligation himself?

Will I get in trouble for doing this?

Comment: Stop doing this right now.

Comment: You went from "*maybe* the third time" to "30 to 40 times"..? If things seemed shady by the 3rd time, why on Earth would you continue to do it another 27+ times??

Comment: 30 times? I really hope you didn't take money yourself for "helping" him.

Comment: It's worth noting that his explanation does not make any logical sense. MoneyGram's monthly limit is on the order of [$3,000](https://bizfluent.com/info-8367124-guidelines-moneygram-limits.html). Funds for his family to travel to the US would not require an acquaintance to make 30-40 transfers; no family trip costs that much unless you're booking on the Four Seasons private jet tour. It's a lie.

Comment: I agree broots.    The only thing I can say is I have been known to be gullible. Or persuaded.    but certainly not slow. I guess at this point I’m very tired of doing it and I begin to question why all of this was going on. Everyone of you made some form of a valid point. I have decided I am no longer going to Participate in the unknown.. And no Serge, I accepted no money.  It all sounds very strange once it is put into words for me to read

Comment: If you just stop participating rather than following the advice to get a lawyer, you may have to pay all that money back, go to jail or both.

Comment: @ZachLipton: maybe he has a big family

Comment: @ZachLipton: moneygram's limit is $10,000/ month, so this family must be really big if he used his share and needed a stranger share too.

Comment: "someone that I know" Physically know? Went to highschool with? or online-friend?

Comment: How much money has actually been transferred?

Comment: Every paycheck, maybe.  Every 2-3 days, though?  Sounds extra-suspicious.

Comment: Usually in these cases, "someone I know casually/friend" turns out to be someone OP only knows *entirely from the Internet*.  And then it turns out OP is the victim of a confidence game: the money they wired is good money, but the check they were paid with ***bounces***.

Comment: @Harper Exactly. I unrolled the comment section to point out, that most of the times word "friend" appears in questions on this site, the person it refers to is not friend at all.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek - Unlikely there is any way the OP could be asked for the money back as the source has intentionally kept his name off all transactions and the money he was handed has in fact been sent and received.

Comment: @Harper - The OP writes that the guy hands him the money.

Comment: If you are comfortable with it, once all of this is over it would be interesting to know how it ended. It would be *very* instructive to hear it first-hand from someone who's been through it, and it could even help others, preventing them from falling for it. In any case, best of luck!

Answer (score 218):

1. **Stop doing this**. If your friend contacts you, don't answer until you've followed through on step 2.
2. **Go get a lawyer**. They might advise you to contact the police and tell the police what's been going on before you get a knock on the door with a warrant behind it.

Here is why: you are almost certainly inadvertently participating in money laundering. The funds are going through you and being "cleaned".

Comment: we need a fusion tool to get both answers together and have the perfect answer : advice and explanation. This gives advice, @Aganju's answer gives explanation

Comment: @everyone We have two. One is called “Add an answer”. The other is called “Edit”. :D

Comment: I know, I just thought that the idea of a button that would go all dragon ball z fusion to create the ultimate answer pretty fun.

Comment: Seriously though, OP, do this.  Especially the lawyer part - don't go *directly* to the police - do so with a lawyer's guidance, for your own protection.

Comment: OK, I certainly am going to cease Doing this at once! The fear factor here is now Will any of it leak back to me In the event something unsavory is taking place? I feel sick from knowing that I may have done something illegal Without first asking the questions that was important.

Comment: @Lawrence: and the one which is missing is *merge* to combine everything together and have a complete answer. The alternative is to edit the question to prefix it with "this is the explanation, see XXX for the advice" and vice-versa

Comment: @Palpus: "The fear factor here is now Will any of it leak back to me In the event something unsavory is taking place?" – Yes, it definitely will! You are the only person that it *can* leak back to, since you are the only person whose name is on that money. That is the whole point of this exercise: to make sure that *your* name and *only your* name is associated with whatever criminal enterprise this money is coming from and/or going to. You are likely laundering money for a criminal enterprise or funding one (or a terrorist group), *and you are putting your name on everything*.

Comment: @Palpus - Please take the lawyer advice seriously, and be aware that this is an **urgent** situation. If *you* go to the police (with your lawyer, on your lawyer's advice) you're performing a public service: Reporting what is almost certainly a crime, one that you have inadvertently been caught up in. That may be helpful to you, mitigating the negative consequences. If the *police* come to *you* (and after all, it's your name on the paperwork), the situation is very, very different.

Comment: @Palpus It might be useful to mention *why* you should do step 2 before answering your friend again - you definitely don't want your "friend" to know that you are onto him, as until that point you have more leverage with law enforcement to cooperate so they can try to catch him (if that is what your lawyer advises, of course!).

Answer (score 115):

Scam/Criminal.

There is no limit how much money he can send into the world, so the excuse is BS.

Of course, nobody can say for sure, but the chances are that it is money laundering: *Illegally acquired cash* is paid in, and the receiver sends it right back as a clean electronic transfer. When the FBI (or the DEA or another alphabet-soup agency) catches up with it, they will knock on your door, your ID will be on the transfers, and you will go to jail for money laundering. Your 'friend' probably has a dozen other friends already doing that for him, and none of them knows his real name.

Comment: Yeah, but your answer is missing a crucial part -> the solution.

Comment: @DonQuiKong how so? There were 3 questions: will OP get in trouble, what is the third party doing, why can't the third party do it himself. All three answered above; yes he will get in trouble, the third party is laundering money, and the essential component to money laundering is you don't do things yourself if it draws the authorities' attention to you. Those are the solutions to the questions.

Comment: @tjbp sure, but none of those solves the problem. “Do I have a problem with this?“ “yep, you're screwed“. There's the *go to a lawyer asap* missing

Comment: The limit is of Money Gram, not everything else. Still BS, I know.

Comment: @DonQuiKong Where is the question asking for a solution?  The title asks what is going on and the last sentence in the body asks if he can get into trouble, but they never ask if there is something he should do to minimize the trouble they could get into.

Comment: There are actually various limits that could be encountered. Many services have a limit on the amount that can be sent without additional identification (of the user, the source of funds, etc, the whole KYC). It's usually cumulative, though, but the details may vary, and there may be a limit per month or other time period instead. Then there are limits over which such transfers are reported. In practice, splitting payments does not help (quite the contrary), but scammers do not necessarily know so.

Comment: @DonQuiKong "go to a lawyer asap" is not a solution - no lawyer can solve a problem such as this, but what they can do is give further advice which may lead to a resolution. So, not even "get a lawyer" answers are actually providing a solution, just another step down the road...

Comment: @Moo That's a nitpick. Sure, "get legal representation right now" is not the end goal, but given the amount of shit that OP is presumably in it is a **very important** next step. Further, we don't do legal advice here (and certainly not in what might easily be a criminal matter), so any other "solution" would probably not be in line with Stack Exchange guidelines.

Comment: I have to admit I'm a bit puzzled by the comments seemingly arguing that telling the OP that they should get a lawyer is extraneous knowledge that is off-topic because the OP didn't explicitly ask for next steps.

Answer (score 8):

He is doing this so **you will go to jail** when he finances terror with his money. Or any other unsavoury thing he wants to send money for. Paying for child porn. Laundering money. None of us know, but you'll be the one hanging for it.

Answer (score 3):

@Palpus - While everyone here has (correctly) identified the fact that you are probably involved in [money laundering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_laundering), one thing that has not been provided in the answers so far is a *specific* response to your `"Will I get in trouble for doing this?"` part of the question.

The short answer is **YES, AND GET A LAWYER NOW!**

Besides the fact that you are likely participating (knowingly or not) in a criminal activity, there is the additional issue of *tax evasion*. Even if you just stop participating you are now logged in MoneyGram's records as having **cumulatively** "given away" XXX dollars/euros (whatever currency your country uses) and those records will routinely end up in the hands of your tax authorities where they will be considered [unreported income](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_evasion) that you will owe taxes and penalties on. You could even be charged with a felony depending on how much money in total was involved.

So even if you have already terminated contact with this guy, you MUST get a lawyer NOW and protect yourself from the financial & legal problems that almost certainly will show up eventually as a result of what has been happening.

Answer (score -1):

I want to add to these answers, the concern I have over "someone I know". How well do you know them? If the police or organised crime/FBI style of law enforcement knock on your door, or get involved, you will go a long way to clear yourself of other than claiming personal naivety, if you can identify the "someone". The concern I have is that I don't know, from your question, if you can do so.

Your problem is that there is no trace where the money came from, where it went, or who has it now. A reasonable assumption would be that you signed everything, so an associate of yours has ended up holding it. So suspicion is likely, and your defense will have a high chance of sounding flimsy.

It's a bit underhand but as there seems a very high chance  1) there is serious criminal activity going on, 2) you're being used as a fall guy and set up by this "someone" in it, I would be a bit willing to do the following:

1. Get the guy's fingerprints on something. A phone you offer them to look at a picture, a glass, a can of soda, whatever it is that you can give him as part of ordinary conversation, that he would take without thinking, then give back or put down, and you can hold without rubbing the new prints.
2. Get a photo at some time. If it's a criminal matter, you can bet that the moment there's a wisp of any issue, or he pulls out (and you might not know when it happens), he might never be seen again. All you'll have is a story about "someone". A photo will be very useful in worst cases, if you can take one without being seen.

**Then**, if you contact the police or they knock on your door, or accuse you/hint they think you were a knowing party, you have something concrete to give beyond a vague description.

At which point, **now** contact a lawyer, who may well then say to go to the police. A lawyer may well be important to ensure you minimise the risk of issues when you do so.

Comment: Going to the police without a lawyer is a really bad idea.

Comment: Conducting an undercover operation to identify the other party without having the police, a lawyer, a prosecutor, and possibly a backup emergency response team involved even more so.

Comment: R - edited last paragraph to reflect this. Lucky to live myself in a country and of a group with privilege, where I automatically take it for granted I can go to the police without a lawyer. I'd overlooked that many don't have that luxury and good fortune, here and elsewhere. A humbling thought. Thank you.

Comment: Jorg - I wasn't suggesting that. Just get enough that anyone could get, who meets somebody regularly in person and is on some degree of friendship/acquaintance with them - prints on some everyday object (glass, wallet, phone, paper) and/or a photo. Not difficult and not even risky. I agree, going "undercover" to "identify" them is far more and I wouldn't have suggested that. That's for the police to do, if they choose.

Comment: @Stilez I am not sure such a country exists. I live in Sweden, and even here I would certainly not recommend **anybody** to go to the police in such a matter without legal representation. Even if you live in a country where the police tends to be your friend, you really, really want to be on the safe side when it comes to what could easily be serious criminal allegations.

Comment: @xLeitix - Its more individual belief/attitude. Rightly or not, there will always be some proportion of a community who would feel safe and appropriate to do that. Whether they are, objectively, correct in that belief is a different matter. I imagine some are, some aren't. All I can say is, I wrote what I did, because (rightly or not) I would myself feel safe to do so, and to handle a suspicious officer or knowing when to get a lawyer if needed. But I removed it because many people would be better advised not to do so, and its a safer bet, especially given US police approaches track record.

Comment: @Stilez There is absolutely no reason to try and identify this person (or get information to help) before going to the police, and it's dangerous advice to recommend OP try it. First of all, you're asking OP to try and gather information on a known criminal. That's not safe at all. On top of that, the police are going to be better at this than OP. They know what information to look for and the best techniques to get it. They'll have better ways to identify this person and to gather evidence they participated in a crime.

Comment: @Stilez Police wouldn't appreciate it at *all* if you showed up to their precinct saying you've known about criminal activity, but it's ok, because you have a smudged fingerprint on a cup. They *will* appreciate you saying you went straight to them (with a lawyer) once you identified a crime and that you want to help them. That's the best path towards leniency. Lastly, the path to leniency depends on OP actually being helpful. The police are professionals at making the things OP knows helpful; they are literally the best option available. Why would you possibly suggest another route?

Comment: I know you mean well but of course I have to downvote for the suggestion that this OP, who's already potentially in massive legal trouble, turn vigilante/bounty hunter/spy and start taking photos of the criminal and try to obtain their fingerprints. Just... what? You could literally get them killed. _Let the police do their job._

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not to mention, at present OP's help could provide the police a ton of assistance in tracking down this criminal and any other criminal activity they may be involved in. Not to be rude to OP, but if they weren't aware they were being used to launder money, I'm not confident they could discretely gather information from this man. If he figures out OP is poking around asking questions, there's a fair chance the police lose a strong opportunity to catch this guy. Vigilantism is also discouraged (illegal?) because it can *easily* ruin opportunities to decrease crime.

Comment: @LordFarquaad Right!